# Swift 2とRealmSwiftでコンパイルエラー: Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

Tags: swift, realm

サンプルでは以下のようになっています。

```
// Person model
class Person: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var birthdate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1)
}

// Create a Person object
let author = Person()
author.name = "David Foster Wallace"

// Get the default Realm
let realm = Realm()
// You only need to do this once (per thread)

// Add to the Realm inside a transaction
realm.write {
  realm.add(author)
}
```

しかし、以下の行がエラーになってしまいます。

```
let realm = Realm()
```

特にRealm()の部分のようです。
環境はXCODE7Bata5です。
改善策か、間違いを指摘していただければ幸いです。

一応

```
import RealmSwift
```

も、しています。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift 2ではエラー処理の方法として新たに`try`、`catch`、`throw`というキーワードと文法が導入されました。

https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=29
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html

RealmSwiftのAPIも標準のエラー処理の方法に沿うように、Swift 2からはAPIが変更されていますので、それに合わせて変更する必要があります。

具体的には、`Realm`をインスタンス化はエラーが起こる可能性（書き込み権限が無い、パスが間違っている、など）のある処理ですので、エラー処理が必要になります。

下記のように`do-try-catch`構文にて何らかのエラーが発生した場合は`catch`節でエラー処理をします。

```
do {
    let realm = try Realm()

    realm.write {
        realm.add(author)
    }
} catch {
    // Error handling...
}
```

または、エラー処理が不要で無視する場合は`try!`を使うこともできます。

```
let realm = try! Realm()

realm.write {
    realm.add(author)
}
```

Comment: データベース名の指定と、データベースのありかを指定する方法も教えていただけないでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: StackOverflowではコメント欄で質問と回答をしたり、コメントの質問に回答を追加することは、他の利用者が気づかなかったり、タイトルと異なった内容の回答がつくことになるので推奨されません。別の質問として作成するようにしてください。そうすれば私も回答できます。

Comment: すみませんでした。質問を立てたので、よろしくお願いいたします。